# Sccs/Sass compiling to CSS

Tags: css, sass, compiler-construction

does someone knows how to program a compiler that compiles SCCS/SASS to CSS without a VSCode extention? Can someone explain which language you need and maybe a basic concept? Thanks!

Comment: you don't need to create one from zero, just download one from npm (official one): here a very detailed video that help me a lot, maybe can help you also: https://youtu.be/o4cECvhrBo8 (it's from Kevin Powell) --- maybe use a bundle with that (but if you use react or similar, it's already built in for you. I like **vite** because is easy, but there is also webpack, etc...)

Comment: Do you mean a real compiler for the language or maybe a taskrunner (like Gulp ou Grunt) that runs a compiling task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to create your "own" sass compiler. 
You could use "bundlers" like [Parcel.js](https://parceljs.org/) or [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) where you have to write your own logic, to compile the sass/scss files. 
Another way which could be similar like webpack is to use task runners like [Gulp](https://gulpjs.com/) or [Grunt](https://gruntjs.com/).
Most of them will rely on some third party packages like [node-sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass) (it is deprecated now) or [dart sass](https://sass-lang.com/dart-sass). 
Of course if you don't want to burn much time to learn one of these options (webpack, gulp, grunt) you could always write your own compiler with node.js 

For me, I prefer to use **webpack** . Just have to write my `webpack.config.js` file once and could use it almost everywhere in my pet projects. 
For most of these you will only need some javascript and you are good to go.
Hope it helps!